# How to create new variable but not a link to old variable?

Tags: python

I tried to create 3 new variables **b,c,d** based on **a**:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = a
c = b
d = c
```

but when I do this:

```
d[4]=5000
print(a)
```

It doesn't print the original **a** but **d**.

How can I print the original **a**?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you could use a quick guide to [how variables and objects interact in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).